# How to subscribe webhooks in OneNote

Tags: onenote

I am trying to integrate OneNote with third party application. There is no clear documentation for subscribing webhooks. So, how to subscribe webhooks?

Answer (score 0):

You can read this 
[Subscribe for webhooks to get change notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-sync)

you can message them on their twitter handle, they will then mail you asking for few requirements, following which you can subscribe to webhooks